# Filter multiple values in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filtering

I need to filter an object by multiple values.

Example of object:

```
items: [
{
url: "https://...",
id: "1693",
type: "ABC",
currencyCode: "SEK",
longName: "Abc",
name: "ABC",
micCode: "DEF",
listingDate: "2018-05-25T00:00:00+02:00",
subType: "STOCK",
  market: {
   id: "NOROTC"
},
}
.....
```

If I filter one value it's fine:

```
var market = data.filter(item => item.market.id === 'NOROTC');
```

But what I need to do is something like:

```
var market = data.filter(item => item.market.id === 'NOROTC' && item.market.id === 'NGM');
```

I found some similar posts here on stackoverflow but none of them seems to work in my case.
Is there a smart way to do this? I tried _.filter() aswell but to no success...

Comment: if `id` is **NOROTC** it cannot be **NGM** at the same time. If you're looking to filter items with the `id` of **NOROTC** or **NGM**, use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for an `OR` operator? Try using `||`

Comment: Yes of course, what's what I need... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below example:

```js
var items = [{
    name: 'Amit',
    id: 101
  },
  {
    name: 'Amit',
    id: 1011
  },
  {
    name: 'Arthit',
    id: 102
  },
  {
    name: 'Misty',
    id: 103
  },
]

var filteredData = items.filter(item => item.name == 'Amit' || item.name== 'Misty');

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array of IDs you want to filter and use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to filter array as following:

```js
var items = [
  {market: {id: "NOROTC"}},
  {market: {id: "NGM"}},
  {market: {id: "foo"}},
  {market: {id: "bar"}},
]

var searchItems = ["NOROTC","NGM"]

var filteredData = items.filter(item => searchItems.includes(item.market.id))

console.log(filteredData)
```

Hope this helps.